# Dynamic df len using date

Tags: python, function, indexing, range

I have a function that I am trying to amend so that it only returns values that are within the last 3 months.

In its current form the function looks like this and returns a value from previous rows based on 'original_function':

```
def transform_function(values):
    return [original_function(values, i) for i in range(len(values))]
```

So in my inexperienced python mind, what I am looking for is something like this:

```
def transform_function(values, dates):
    return [original_function(values, i) 
               for i in range(len(dates[i] - (dates[i] - 3*datedelta.MONTH)))]
```

Unfortunately, what looks good in my mind does work in code (no surprise there!)

Please can I get some help to convert whats in my mind, into a working solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the error here is caused by an un-defintion of `i` then you can do a nested loop method in the list-comprehension to solve it. Should look something like this

```
def transform_function(values, dates):
    return [original_function(values, k) #changed i to j
               for k in range(len(dates[i] - (dates[i] - 3*datedelta.MONTH))) for i in range(j) if i==j ]
```

This way `i` is defined and the condition ensures that you only run it once each time and not n*n. It's not efficient by runtime but should solve your problem.

**Edit:**

Just realised that the code above would still give you an error, as `i` when refereed to is undefined. The only way you can solve this is to find the length in advance, e.g.

```
ctr = len(dates) -1
```

and now simply use the `ctr` value in the list-comprehension method

```
return [original_function(values, k) 
              for k in range(ctr) for i in range(len(dates[k] - (dates[k] - 3*datedelta.MONTH)))  if i==k  ]
```

Hopefully should solve the problem.

Comment: When executing, I get an error .....TypeError: object of type 'Timedelta' has no len()

Comment: @windwalker the error happens here `ctr = len(dates) -1` and this just means that the type of `dates` is not an array. It needs to be of type array to get the length. What is the type of this? if you can simply convert them to an array and the error shouldnt rise again.

Answer (score 0):

It does work like this actually :)

```py
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.now() # for current time
dt.timedelta(months=3) # for time delta
dt.datetime.strftime(dates[i], format='%Y-%m-%d') # for transforming strings to real date objects
```

**timedeltas** can easily be added to **datetime** objects, and datetime objects are substractable

EDIT :

No actually I absolutely don't understand what you're trying to do...

You want to enumerate days ? Easy with timedelta.

What is dates in your function ? What type ? What does it contain ?